# How to pass generated url to formbuilder outside the controller without encoding it

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have a dashboard and on it i have 3 anchors. Every anchor opens different form that is processed by different action in my Home controller.
In twig, i call

```
       {{render(controller('AppBundle:Home/Home:changePersonalInfo')) }}
```

This is the action called in twig:

```
    public function changePersonalInfoAction(Request $request){

    $user = $this->getUser();

    $usertype = new UserType($this->generateUrl('changedetails'));

    $formAccount = $this->createForm($usertype, $user);

    if($request->isMethod("POST"))
    {
        $formAccount->handleRequest($request);

        if($formAccount->isValid())
        {
            $data = $formAccount->getData();
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->persist($data);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }

    return array(
        'formAccount' => $formAccount->createView(),
    );
}
```

In this action, i generate an URL that is then passed to the formbuilder in the userType class:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
private $target_action;

/**
 * @param Router
 */
public function __construct($target_action)
{
    $this->target_action = $target_action;
}


public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->setAction($this->target_action);
```

So that the form can know which action should it be submitted to.
However, when I submit the form i am redirected to

```
/home%23change_details
```

instead of

```
/home#change_details
```

This happens ONLY when i build form in any other place than the controller (i tried doing it in twig by putting

```
<form action="{{ path(mypath) }}" ...
```

in the form block and it produced the same output) When i build my form inside of my controller everything works smoothly. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set action as an option from controller.
No need to pass it as a constructor parameter:

```
$formAccount = $this->createForm($usertype,$user,array(
                                'action'=>$this->generateUrl('changedetails'));
```